# New method to compute square roots

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

In 2011 when I was in school I created a formula to calculate square roots... For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$ the following holds:
$$\sqrt{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{3}{2}-k\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{n}}{n!}$$

It was mostly a joke and the formula is not useful. Recently I stumbled upon this formula again, and decided to work on the ideas behind that formula, not on the formula itself, to create new formulas that are actually useful. With "useful" I mainly mean a good rate of convergence, whatever "good" exactly means in this context...

If you're curious about the specifics of how everything unfolded (and if you either understand German or are willing to use a translator): [The regarding thread on matheplanet.com](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=162777)

I've finished my work for now and, in my opinion, the results are quite nice. However, as I don't have a background in mathematics (I did not study mathematics), I don't know whether these things already exist, or whether they could potentially be useful. I haven't proven anything yet, but I am still confident that it's all correct.

I'd be grateful to get some information about my results from people who actually know mathematics, since I really have no idea what to think of my work.

Let $x,a \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and let $\sqrt{x} \neq a > \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} > 0$ hold

We define
$$S(x,a,m) := \sum_{k=0}^{m}\left(\sum_{n=k}^{m}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\left(4n^2-1\right)2^{2n+1}}\binom{n}{k}\right)\left(-1\right)^{k+1}a^{1-2k}x^{k}\right)$$
$$S(x,a) := \lim_{m\to\infty}S(x,a,m) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\left(4n^2-1\right)2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}a^{1-2k}x^{k}\right)\right)$$
It holds:
$$\forall m : S(x,a,m) \neq S(x,a) = \sqrt{x}$$

We define $\hat{a} := x+1$ and $z := S(x,\hat{a},m)$ which yields:
$$\sqrt{x} = S(x,z) = S(x,S(x,x+1,m))$$

Since I don't have any proofs, I used Mathematica at least... The [Mathematica output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBbiM.png) and the regarding [Mathematica notebook](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/dl.php?id=2472&1683559031).

Using [Nest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) I created a really quick & dirty (& (very) inefficient) iteration to make it converge fast.

Iterating $5$ times with $m=10$ and $x=2$ yields over $34000$ correct decimal places for $\sqrt{2}$.

$m=11$ yields over $51000$ correct decimal places.

It boils down to: The bigger $m$, the faster the iteration converges... $\text{¯\_(ツ)_/¯}$

In other words: You calculate $S(x,a,m)$ for a given $m$ once, the result is an easy function, see the [Mathematica output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBbiM.png) for $S(x,x+1,10)$ as an example. You can save that function, and use it for the iteration.

Furthermore $S(x,a,m)$ and consequently $S(x,x+1,m)$ are (hopefully) easy to compute.
Note that the outer sum runs from $k=0$ to $m$ and $a^{1-2k}x^{k}$ is nicely isolated at the end, so that everything in front of $a^{1-2k}x^{k}$ yields the coefficients.

For $S(x,a)$ everything is "rearranged", so that we do not get nested infinity due to $m\to\infty$.

To get nice $\sqrt{x}$ formulas we can e. g. do the following...
For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$ holds:
$$\sqrt{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\left(4n^2-1\right)2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\left(x+1\right)^{1-2k}x^{k}\right)\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi}n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\left(x+1\right)^{1-2k}x^{k}\right)\right)$$

Kind of by accident (I looked at $\sqrt{\pi}$) I also obtained the following two formulas:
$$\sqrt{\pi}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\left(4n^2-1\right)2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\pi^{1-k}\right)\right)$$
$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\pi^{1-k}\right)\right)$$

The last one is just supposed to look cool... For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$ holds:

$$\sqrt{x}=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{p-1}\frac{\left(\sum_{q=0}^{m}\left(-1\right)^{q-1}\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{1-2q}}{q!}\frac{\Gamma\left(q-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x-(x+1)^2\right)^{q}\right)^{1-2p}}{p!}\frac{\Gamma\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x-\left(\sum_{r=0}^{m}\left(-1\right)^{r-1}\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{1-2r}}{r!}\frac{\Gamma\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x-(x+1)^2\right)^{r}\right)^2\right)^{p}$$

**Edit**:

- I guess I should include, that I've never been able to speak to someone about my mathematics in my whole life, so I really have no idea...
- "Working in isolation" was mentioned in the comments. I'd like to clarify: Although I've worked in isolation only, that's not what I want. I simply didn't know who to speak to...

**Answer to [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446587/504411)**:
While thinking about writing down what I did in regard to the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ I noticed that I'm now able to ask specific questions.

However: I haven't developed abstract enough mathematics to express those questions, yet.

Consequence: I'll develop the needed mathematics, and when I've done so I'll edit this question (again) to ask those questions and I'll also explain what I did in regard to the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ to give some context.

(Or should I open a new post, then? If so, please let me know)

Comment: You can simplify $\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{n}$ to $\frac{(-1)^n}{2}(x+1)^{1-2n}(x-1)^{2n}$. That looks like a good first step. Also $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{3}{2} - k \right)}{n!}$ can be written as $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Wojowu I quote myself: However, as I don't have a background in mathematics (I did not study mathematics), I don't know whether these things already exist, or whether they could potentially be useful. [...] I'd be grateful to get some information about my results from people who actually know mathematics, since I really have no idea what to think of my work.

Comment: While I agree that this fits the bill for closing as a request to check results, I think an exception should be made in this case -- the OP has made it clear that they see no alternative routes available, and the question is well-received. I believe we have sufficiently skilled number theorists and analysts (and analytical number theorists) to either validate or dunce cap this post, so let them have at it.

Comment: @AlecRhea Yeah, I'm sorry that I'm not even able to come up with concrete questions, but since I really know nothing about mathematics, there is no sensible place for me to start... And it would be fantastic if someone would destroy everything I did, because that would be a great learning opportunity for me. And that's what it's about, I want to learn... It's (sadly) like I wrote in my **Edit**, I don't know a single person who talks with me about my mathematics, and I also never knew such a person... I do mathematics for fun, but doing it alone isn't fun...

Comment: As someone working in isolation (outside of my interactions on this site), I can sympathize; lucky for us, the community here is generally very welcoming as long as you 'do your homework' at home, and rife with experts in almost every field imaginable. You've come to the right place :^).

Comment: I'm still a bit at a loss what the question is; Mathematica evaluates these sums in closed-form, indeed giving $\sqrt x$, are you interested in a derivation "by hand" ?

Comment: I understand that the OP is "requesting information," for example, has this result been published before, are there more general results, etc.

Comment: @JRN Exactly, such questions I mean.

Comment: Q: "Or should I open a new post, then?" --- yes, please, posts on MO are not "living documents", a new question goes into a new post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me "unclutter" the basic formula $S(x,a)=\sqrt{x}$, starting from the definition in the OP,
$$S(x,a) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\left(4n^2-1\right)2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}a^{1-2k}x^{k}\right)\right).$$
The finite sum over $k$ is the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) of $-a(1-x/a^2)^n$, and with some further algebra we have
$$S(x,a)=-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right) }{ \Gamma (n+1)}\left(1-x/a^2\right)^n.$$
This is simply the Taylor series of $a\sqrt {x/a^2}=\sqrt{x}$ around $x=1$, independent of $a>0$.

So I am unsure whether $S(x,a)$ has more content than just this, a power series of $\sqrt x$ around $x=1$.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I do everything again in my head (to create the formulas), from start to finish, while writing down what I'm doing? I could do that for the 2011 formula as well...

Comment: During creating the formulas, I had something (kind of)? similar to your "uncluttered" version in my head: [The formula at the bottom](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=162777&post_id=1903492)

Comment: Sadly, I cannot follow your thoughts... What do I need to know, in order to be able to understand the logic behind your reasoning? What does "simply linear in $y$" even mean? I started with the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ and based on that I got my formulas, does that information help? And I'm still wondering whether or not it could be helpful, if I explain in detail, how I arrived at those formulas. If anyone feels like it could be of use, let me know and I'll do it, but it could take a couple of days...

Comment: I worked it out a bit more; as far as I can see, after "uncluttering", only the Taylor series of $\sqrt x$ around $x=1$ remains --- or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: I guess you are not oversimplifying because my main idea behind all of that is really simple. Cool. I'll write down what I did in regard to the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ and will edit it into my question...